# Excel convert bytes to HEX

Tags: excel

I have a column with bytes like this:

```
b'6\x9f\x01\xdf,\x05\x1e\xea\xa2\xd8\x83W0\x8c_\xbf'
b'\xdeT\x1d\x043\x02\x1e\xdc\xa2\xb2\x13\x8dD\x0b\x12\x1b'
b'^Lj\x0e\x00\x04\x1e\xec\x9b\xe0\x0c>Q%\xda\xc8'
b'`\x92\xef\xec\r\xee\x16\x00\xe1\x00\x80\xdb\xac\x14l\xd3'
```

Is there any way to convert them to HEX values?

Comment: What do those values even mean? `\x9f`, does that mean `9F` in hexadecimal (decimal value 159)? In that case, the following one, `\x01`, why is there `\x` in front of it (if it were `\x9f01`, would that mean the same or something else? ...? Whatever is means, did you try the standard Excel function `=Hex.N.Dec()` (might be slightly different in English, my Excel is Dutch)?

Comment: I don't know of any way in Excel (it may as well be possible), but if you'd load your data in for example [Python](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/python-convert-byte-to-hex/), there are specific methods to turn a byte-literal into hex.